# payUmoney integration is giving an error

Tags: android, payumoney

After logging in, it's generating a hash value, but still giving error *"Some problem occurred! try again"*.

```
PayUmoneySdkInitilizer.PaymentParam.Builder builder =
    new PayUmoneySdkInitilizer.PaymentParam.Builder();

builder.setAmount(10.0)
       .setTnxId("0nf7" + System.currentTimeMillis())
       .setPhone(<My phone>)
       .setProductName("product_name")
       .setFirstName(<My Name>)
       .setEmail(<My email>)
       .setsUrl("https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/success.php")
       .setfUrl("https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/failure.php")
       .setUdf1("").setUdf2("").setUdf3("").setUdf4("").setUdf5("")
       .setIsDebug(false)
       .setKey(<mykey>)
       .setMerchantId(<my debug merchant id>);

String tnxId="0nf7" + System.currentTimeMillis();
PayUmoneySdkInitilizer.PaymentParam paymentParam = builder.build();
String hashSequence = "<...>|"+tnxId+"|10.0|product_name|<My name>|<My email>|||||||||||salt";
String serverCalculatedHash= hashCal("SHA-512", hashSequence);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
               serverCalculatedHash, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
paymentParam.setMerchantHash(serverCalculatedHash);
// calculateServerSideHashAndInitiatePayment(paymentParam);
PayUmoneySdkInitilizer.startPaymentActivityForResult(TrayActivity.this, paymentParam);
```

---

```
public static String hashCal(String type, String str) {
    byte[] hashseq = str.getBytes();
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
        algorithm.reset();
        algorithm.update(hashseq);
        byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();
        for (int i = 0; i<messageDigest.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF &messageDigest[i]);
            if (hex.length() == 1) { hexString.append("0"); }
            hexString.append(hex);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } return hexString.toString();
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Some error occurred.. try again later

Answer (score 0):

You use in the code:

```
.setTnxId("0nf7" + System.currentTimeMillis())
```

And then later:

```
String tnxId="0nf7" + System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Probably not the only problem, but do you really want to use two different values for these (the time may change between the two calls)? Didn't you want the same `tnxId` in both cases?

---

TransactionIdProvider.java:

```
import java.util.Locale;

public class TransactionIdProvider {

    private final static String DEFAULT_PREFIX = "ID";

    // Convenient prime number for incrementing the counter
    private final static long ID_ADD = 0xF0AD;  // "f*ck off and die"

    // 64b counter with non-trivial start value
    private static long idCounter = 0x0101F00DDEADBEEFL;

    /**
     * Returns ID consisting of prefix string and 64b counter interleaved
     * with 32b per-4s-timestamp.
     * 
     * May produce identical ID (collision) when:
     * 1) class is reloaded within 4s
     *    (to fix: serialize "idCounter" upon shutdown/restart of VM, or
     *    modify prefix per start of VM)
     * 2) more than 2^64 IDs are requested within 4s (no fix, unexpected)
     * 3) more than 2^64 IDs are requested after cca. 550 years.
     *    (no fix, unexpected)
     * 4) more than one static instance of TransactionIdProvider is used
     *    (two or more VMs running the app) (to fix put different prefix in
     *    every VM/server running this)
     * 
     * Length of returned ID is prefix.length() + 24 alphanumeric symbols.
     */
    public static synchronized String getNewId(final String prefix) {
        idCounter += ID_ADD;    // increment counter
        // get 32b timestamp per ~4s (millis/4096) (good for ~550 years)
        final int timeStamp = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis()>>12);
        final int idPart1 = (int)(idCounter>>32);
        final int idPart2 = (int)(idCounter);
        return String.format(Locale.US, "%s%08X%08X%08X",
                             prefix, idPart1, timeStamp, idPart2);
    }

    public static String getNewId() {
        return getNewId(DEFAULT_PREFIX);
    }

}
```

Not sure how much usable is this one, and if the ID may be so long. Feel free to use/modify it any way you wish.

Also I wonder, whether I didn't forget about something important, but can't recall anything.

The security aspect of this one is still quite weak, as within 4s time span the ID will be like simple addition, but at least it's not producing 1, 2, 3... series.

---

Did found some SDK docs, looks like txnId may be 25 chars long, so you have 1 char for prefix only. Or cut down on timestamp, using `%07X` in format and masking value with 0x0FFFFFFF, that would make it repeat every ~34 years -> 2 letters for prefix. Or change counter to 32b `int`, should be still more than enough, unless you expect thousands of transactions per second -> that would remove 8 chars. Or base32/base64 the whole ID to shorten it (depends what alphabet is legal for content)...

Or whatever... already spent enough time with this. Hire a pro.

Comment: yes i want to .. actually this is first time i'm trying for payment gateway

Comment: @AdityaReja so move the `String tnxId` above, to define it only once, then use the same value (per transaction) everywhere, where transaction Id is required. Actually `timeMillis` as "suffix" is probably bad idea too, if your solution will be used by two people at the almost-same-time, they will create transaction with the same ID. You should probably create some synchronized static counter in separate class and call it's getNewTxId() once per transaction. You may still want to add some time or hash into the process to avoid simple 1,2,3,4,5... IDs for security reasons.

Comment: @AdityaReja BTW, I don't know "PayUmoney SDK", so I have no idea what is that code doing and where further errors may be, but the problem with transactions ids is general, so I'm answering only that one.

Comment: Yeah even I'm trying this for rhe first time !! Please provide me some code to generate new transaction id